# Weekly Date Intervals

Tags: sharepoint-online, date-time

I am trying to get weekly start and end dates displayed automatically (as i am going to be pulling reports weekly, this will be helpful).

For example, if today was monday 6/24 - would like to pull the date automatically in the start date and end date as 6/28 
for next week when i open my view it would display all data for week of 7/1 - 7/5 
etc..

Answer (score 1):

I am not exactly sure what you're asking but I think this will help

[How to filter items in the current calendar month and week](http://blog.pentalogic.net/2009/11/howto-filter-items-current-calendar-month-view-sharepoint/)

This shows current/next/previous *calendar* month and weeks. Its seems a strange way around so read it carefully and try it - it really does work.

Depending on how you define a week (Mon>Sun, Sun > Sat etc) this may be helpful :-

[Complete guide to filtering SharePoints lists by the current week](http://blog.pentalogic.net/2012/09/complete-guide-to-filtering-sharepoint-lists-by-the-current-week/)

Answer (score 0):

To filter a list to show the current week’s items or events, create two calculated columns with a data type of Date and Time (Date Only), and a view with filters based on the new columns.

I’ve included the formulas and view filters below.  [Visit my blog post](https://jennyssharepointtips.wordpress.com/2016/10/22/show-this-week-only/) on this topic for a more in-depth explanation and to view screenshots.

```
Column 1 Name:  Calc_WeekViewEnd
Column 1 Formula:  =[End Time]-WEEKDAY([End Time],2)+7

Column 2 Name:  Calc_WeekViewStart
Column 2 Formula:  =[Calc_WeekViewEnd]-7

View Name:  This Week
View Filters:  Calc_WeekViewStart is less than or equal to [Today], AND, Calc_WeekViewEnd is greater than or equal to [Today]
```